# OTP Input using textfield material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Can we make OTP input using textfield of material UI in react typescript?
I have seen people did it with input field but i am looking if it can be done through textfield of material UI

Comment: Did you try anything? please share your code.

Comment: @HamedSiaban no i couldn't do it

Answer (score 4):

There is a package for Material UI v5 (or MUI) called [Mui OTP input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-one-time-password-input) and it's working with React 17 and 18 !

Simply way to use.

Check the doc here : https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-otp-input

```js
import React from 'react'
import { MuiOtpInput } from 'mui-one-time-password-input'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return <MuiOtpInput length={6} value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```